# trying to sort structures but errors or crashing

Tags: c, sorting, struct, bubble-sort

I am coding a program which will sort the outputs by employee number, from lowest to highest. When I try and use the struct name in front of the temp variable it just says 'unknown type name strPerson'. I'm not too sure what I need to do, and I have only passed the pointer as a parameter as the other values can be retrieved from members within the struct as shown by the if statement.

Comment: Is the struct definition included before `fnEmployeeNumSort` is defined?

Comment: Where is the 5 coming from in the for loop?

Comment: post the full program

Comment: Have you included the file that contains your struct? Anyways, when you get it to compile you're probably going to face issues with `nCount` and `ptrPerson[nCount + 1]`.

Comment: @StoryTeller , I have declared the definitions at the top

Comment: @ChrisTurner the 5 is the size of the array which is holding 5 different people within the main method

Comment: @Luke: you should initialize the index and only loop up to `4` and decrement the index by 2 after the swap if it is non zero.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight This is just a snippet as the whole code is way too large to include as there are multiple methods.

Comment: Read how to create a [mcve], then create one, and [edit] your question to insert it.  You don't just dump your complete source code into a question and hope someone will debug it for you.  Reference: [mcve].  Did I mention that you should reduce your problematic program to a  [mcve]?

Comment: The rest of the program is irrelevant, so for the purpose of the question the code is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I try and use the struct name in front of the temp variable it
>   just says 'unknown type name strPerson'

There is no type `strPerson`. There is type `struct strPerson`. So the compiler issues an error for the declaration

```
strPerson temp = ptrPerson[nCount + 1];
```

You should write at least

```
struct strPerson temp = ptrPerson[nCount + 1];
```

Also the variable `nCount` was not initialized. So the function has undefined behavior.

It is not clear what the magic number 5 means. If it is the size of the passed to the function array then again the function has undefined behavior because the expression `nCount + 1` can be out of the range of valid indices for the array.

The function itself should be declared like

```
void fnEmployeeNumSort( struct strPerson *ptrPerson, size_t n );
```

where the second parameter `n` specifies the size of the sorted sequence.

And at last the function does not perform sorting. The sorting algorithm is implemented incorrectly.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can implement the bubble sort algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct strPerson
{
    int nEmployeeNum;
};

void fnEmployeeNumSort( struct strPerson *ptrPerson, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t last = n; !( n < 2 ); n = last )
    {
        for ( size_t i = last = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( ptrPerson[i].nEmployeeNum < ptrPerson[i - 1].nEmployeeNum )
            {
                struct strPerson temp = ptrPerson[i];
                ptrPerson[i] = ptrPerson[i - 1];
                ptrPerson[i - 1] = temp;
                last = i;
            }
        }
    }       
}

#define N   5

int main(void) 
{
    struct strPerson p[N] = { { 5 }, { 4 }, { 3 }, { 2 }, { 1 } };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", p[i].nEmployeeNum );
    putchar( '\n' );

    fnEmployeeNumSort( p, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", p[i].nEmployeeNum );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: nCount is now initialized, and struct included, now when I run the program it's even worse than before, not sure whats going on

Comment: @Luke I do not know what means "worse than before" but it is evident that the sorting algorithm is implemented incorrectly as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: how would it be done, I've looked at many different examples and have tried to follow them using my own program

Comment: @Luke See my updated post.

Comment: Using this is an improvement, as it now outputs one of the 5 people, then it just crashes still

Comment: @Luke If your program crashes search an error in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple problems in your code:

- `nCount` is uninitialized.  This has undefined behavior and can definitely lead to a crash if it happens to have a negative value.
- type `strPerson` seems undefined, producing a compilation error. Use `struct strPerson` or define `strPerson` with `typedef struct strPerson strPerson;`.
- You also forget to decrement the index after the swap, leading to incorrect sort order.
- The array size is not specified as an argument, the value `5` in the algorithm would correspond to an array of 6 elements.

You should specify the number of elements in the array as an argument and use this variation on your code:

```
void fnEmployeeNumSort(struct strPerson *ptrPerson, size_t count) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        if (ptrPerson[i].nEmployeeNum > ptrPerson[i + 1].nEmployeeNum) {
            struct strPerson temp = ptrPerson[i + 1];
            ptrPerson[i + 1] = ptrPerson[i];
            ptrPerson[i] = temp;
            if (i > 0) {
                i -= 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @StoryTeller: *errors or crashing*.  Answer updated, thanks

Comment: And there's also the problem that this ensures the largest employee number is last, but doesn't ensure the rest are sorted.  There needs to be another level of looping, or some other way to get everything sorted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: the original code had this problem, but decrementing `i` after a swap fixes it. This is the basic *Bubble sort* algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some problems,

1. It's probably crashing because, `nCount` is never initialized, so it's undefined behavior.

   I don't know where the magic `5` comes from or if it's right, but cerainly not initializing `nCount` is a problem,

   ```
   for (nCount = 0; nCount < 5; ++nCount)
   ```

   should fix it.

   Note that I said "*probably*", because a crash is a tricky thing. There might be other wrong pointer manipulation somewhere else, which is why a debugger is very helpful in finding these kind of problems.
2. I suggest passing the number of elements as a parameter.
3. You probably need `struct strPerson` instead of `strPerson`.

   While in the c++ language you can use the structure name directly, in c you can't unless you `typedef` it

   ```
   typedef struct strPerson {
       /* The definition in here */
   } strPerson;
   ```

   then your code would work as it is. (*Fixing (1) first of course.*)

Comment: The algorithm is flawed too.

Answer (score 2):

This line is missing the keyword `struct` at the beginning

```
strPerson temp = ptrPerson[nCount + 1];
```

should be

```
struct strPerson temp = ptrPerson[nCount + 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

this should fix it: `nCount = 0;` in the for loop

and add `struct` before the strPerson

Comment: I've edited my answer